# Debounce input does not read keyboard information

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, debouncing

I need DebounceInput to read information from my keyboard, but when I type in Ervin for example, the whole list stays and not just Ervin as it used to work. I don't really know where I went wrong. I know that Debounce is supposed to wait until the user stops typing, but even after waiting a minute nothing changed.

This is my files:

DebounceInput:

```
import {DebounceInput} from 'react-debounce-input';
type Props ={
   onChange:Function;
}
const Debounce:React.FC<Props> = ({onChange}) => {
  return(
        <DebounceInput
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}             
          debounceTimeout={500}                 
          className="SearchInput"                  
          placeholder="Search by user name..."                  
        />      
  )
}
export default Debounce
```

UsersList:

```
import {UsersContext} from '../../contexts/Users'
type Props = {
    filteredUsers:Array<Person>;
}
type Person = {
    name:string;
    username:string;
}
const UsersList: React.FC = () => {
    const filteredUsers = useContext(UsersContext);

    return(
        <div className="ListHead"> 
            <ol className="list">
                {filteredUsers.map((Person) => (
                    <li key={Person.name}>
                        <span>{Person.name}</span>
                        @{Person.username}
                    </li>
            ))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    )}
```

Users:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

type Users = Person[];
type Person = {
    name:string;
    username:string;
}

export const UsersContext = React.createContext<Users>([]);
const UsersProvider:React.FC= ({children}) => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<Person[]>([]); 
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .then((response) =>{
            setUsers(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },[]);

    return (
        <UsersContext.Provider value={users}>
            {children}
        </UsersContext.Provider>
            
    )
}
```

And Main:

```
const Main:React.FC= () => {
    const [showUser, setShowUser] = useState("");
    return (
    <div>
        <div>
             <Header/>
        </div>
            <UsersProvider>
                <UsersList />
                <Debounce onChange={setShowUser}/>
            </UsersProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your debouncing Input does not do anything except for changing the `showUser` state. Since your users resides in the `UsersProvider` . You can pass the value of your `showUser` as a prop to `UsersProvider` .

```
const Main:React.FC= () => {
  const [showUser, setShowUser] = useState("");
  return (
  <div>
      <div>
           <Header/>
      </div>
          <UsersProvider searchText={showUser}>
              <UsersList />
              <Debounce onChange={setShowUser}/>
          </UsersProvider>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Now inside your `UsersProvider` you can do the following

```
type UsersProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  searchText: string;
}

export const UsersContext = React.createContext<Users>([]);
const UsersProvider:React.FC<UsersProviderProps>= ({children, searchText}) => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<Person[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
    .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    .then((response) =>{
        setUsers(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
},[]);

const filteredUsers = useMemo(() => {
  if(searchText.trim().length > 0 && users.length > 0){
    return users.filter((person) =>
    person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  );
  } else {
  return users;
  }
}, [searchText, users])

    return (
        <UsersContext.Provider value={filteredUsers}>
            {children}
        </UsersContext.Provider>
            
    )
}
```

Comment: edited the code to use `useMemo` instead of `useEffect` which is more suitable for this scenario

Comment: `users.filter((Person) => Person.name.toLowerCase()) ` I filtered users i think but i dont know how to return this

Comment: i must to something like this? `searchText(filteredUsers)`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-satoshi-c8l60?file=/src/Contexts/Users/index.tsx

Comment: When I paste this after typing e.g. Leanne/leanne etc. the whole list disappears

Comment: we should be using includes instead of `===` . Here is the updated sandbox . https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-rain-2bgh6?file=/src/Contexts/Users/index.tsx

Comment: Everything works, jeeez. Thank you so much for your time and help. I am just starting my fun with React and Typescript